# Writing to multiple cells using If Target.Address = " " Then

Tags: vba, excel

I have basic code that allows the values written to this cell to be summed while maintaining the cumulative value.  So if I were to type "4" into the cell, and then type "10" into the cell, the result would be "14" (not just the second value entered of "10").  Here is what I have and I must say that it works.

## #

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldvalue As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Address = "$J$5" Then
        On Error GoTo fixit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = 0 Then oldvalue = 0
        Target.Value = 1 * Target.Value + oldvalue
        oldvalue = Target.Value
fixit:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

## #

However, I want to apply this treatment to more than just cell J5.  Say for example, I want the same code logic applied to cell R5 as well.
Thur far I have tried using

```
OR
```

and I have also tried using

```
If Not Intersect (Target, Range("J5:R5")) Is Nothing Then
```

But each of these approaches ties the two cells together (so that what I enter into one gets summed into both - each cell is summing values added to the other).  I can't figure it out to save my life, so took to this forum in the hopes of finding someone smarter than me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (this is assuming existing logic is correct....not sure why you set old value to 0 if Target = 0 and what value the *1 adds?)

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldvalueJ As Double
Dim oldValueR As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    On Error GoTo fixit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$J$5"
        If Target = 0 Then oldvalueJ = 0
        Target = Target + oldvalueJ
        oldvalueJ = Target
    Case "$R$5"
        If Target = 0 Then oldValueR = 0
        Target = Target + oldValueR
        oldValueR = Target
    End Select
fixit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more dynamic by allowing you to add unlimited cells; it also validates user input

---

**Standard** Module

---

```
Option Explicit    'Generic Module

Public Const WS1_MEM_RNG = "C5,J5,R5"    'Sheet1 memory cells

Public prevWs1Vals As Object

Public Sub SetPreviousWS1Vals()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Sheet1.Range(WS1_MEM_RNG).Cells
        If Len(c.Value2) > 0 Then prevWs1Vals(c.Address) = c.Value2
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Sheet1** Module

---

```
Option Explicit    'Sheet1 Module

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(WS1_MEM_RNG)) Is Nothing Then GetPrevious Target
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub GetPrevious(ByVal cel As Range)

    Dim adr As String:  adr = cel.Address

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not IsError(cel.Value) And IsNumeric(cel.Value2) And Not IsNull(cel.Value) Then
        If IsDate(cel.Value) Then
            cel.NumberFormat = "General"
            cel.Value2 = prevWs1Vals(adr)
        Else
            If cel.Value2 = 0 Then prevWs1Vals(adr) = 0
            cel.Value2 = cel.Value2 + prevWs1Vals(adr)
            prevWs1Vals(adr) = cel.Value2
        End If
    Else
        cel.Value2 = prevWs1Vals(adr)
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

**ThisWorkbook** Module

---

```
Option Explicit    'ThisWorkbook Module

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If prevWs1Vals Is Nothing Then Set prevWs1Vals = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    SetPreviousWS1Vals

End Sub
```

---

It can also enforce positives only

Answer (score 0):

use commas to separate ranges, and add a `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event to record the last user selected cell

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldvalue As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("J5,R5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = 0 Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo fixit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Target.Value + oldvalue
fixit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then oldvalue = Target.Value
End Sub
```